# FTP client sees a file that isn't there... How can I successfully delete/overwrite this "ghost" file?

Tags: file-upload, ftp

So we have a client that creates "training packages" and then uploads them via ftp to their website. They create the training packages in PowerPoint, and then use some program to convert them into html/swf files and package them within a folder. When they upload, they use Filezilla, and just transfer the entire folder over. The folder is uniquely named, uses no spaces or special characters.

These files have uploaded fine for about a year. Recently, they've run into a problem. Whenever they try to upload training package folder, they are immediately presented with the "This file already exists, do you want to overwrite?" message. Except... the folder they're moving is brand new, and the file it's asking to overwrite DOESN'T EXIST. When they choose "Overwrite" the file looks like it transfers, but the file size is wrong, and the training package doesn't work correctly.

This happens with every training package they try to upload. It's not just a badly outputted package. Also, it's always the same file that has the problem--it's the main "player" for the training package, and though it contains different content for every package, it is the same file name (cplayer.swf) every time.

Things they've tried without success:

-Re-uploading the file again by itself, and overwriting

-Deleting the "bad" file and re-uploading the single file - Get the overwrite message again, even though the file DOES NOT EXIST.

-Renaming the file on the server and re-uploading the single file - Get the overwrite message.

-Renaming the single file locally within the package and uploading/renaming it - Won't let us rename because the file already exists.

-Used another FTP client - Same results as above, so not a client specific problem.

-Used a different FTP login - Same results as above, so not a permissions problem.

Other things of note:

-The file is small--it's not a time out problem. Plus, all other files upload fine, and some are a lot larger.

-They've emailed this file to me, and I've uploaded it successfully.

I am completely at my wits end. Does anyone have any ideas where I can at least troubleshoot a little further?

Comment: Why the downvote? I've clearly troubleshooted the problem. I've googled the crap out of it. I tried to be as clear as possible, but it's not an easy problem to describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the non-help, the downvote, and the general lack of response on what was a pretty serious issue for me.

In case anyone else has a similar problem, here's what was going on:

Virus software (specifically Malware Bytes) was blocking THIS ONE SINGLE FILE. All I had to do was exclude the folder that contained the file.